# I am trying to return an array of hashes, but only the last hash is being added to the array?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Here is how I get all the hands

```
def get_all_hands
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.cardplayer.com/rules-of-poker/hand-rankings'))
  hand_hash = {}
  hands_array = []
  doc.css('div#rules-of-poker-accordion').each do |hands|
    hands.css('strong').each do |hand|
      hand_hash[:name] = hand.text
    end
    hands.css('div.rules-cards').each do |hand|
      hand_value = []
      hand.css('img').each do |card|
        hand_value << card.attr('src')
        hand_hash[:value] = hand_value
      end
    end
    hands_array << hand_hash
  end
  hands_array
end
HandScraper.new.get_all_hands
```

This returns:

```
[{:name=>"10. High Card",
:value=>
["/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/3-909f8b1571f834c774576c93eae26594.png",
 "/packages/cards/Large/Club/J-58b4c0f26e3e0cf8c0772ab3e9e34784.png",
 "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/8-60d335b08119f600c3ca02aa58fa902d.png",
 "/packages/cards/Large/Heart/4-712ce04b7f2c7e588c48a1e2b46a4244.png",
 "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/2-e2d1cee5fc0db0b70990036153d57906.png"]}]
```

which is the tenth and final hand, when I want it to return all 10.

Comment: You're using a single hash. That doesn't explain why you get a single result back; you should get back an array of references to the single hash.

Comment: @DaveNewton: That's because the loop is just one cycle rather than iteration over the rules.

Comment: @kiddorails Ok; didn't look at the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

This particular piece of code is reason why it doesn't work. You are iterating on each `strong` assigning the value to the same key (`:name`) of `hand_hash`. Same is the case with next iteration. Basically, you are overriding the same hash without saving it anywhere, until last iteration.

```
hands.css('strong').each_with_index do |hand, index|
  hand_hash[index] = hand.text
end
```

I made some changes in your own code to fix this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.cardplayer.com/rules-of-poker/hand-rankings'))
hands_array = []
doc.css('div#rules-of-poker-accordion').each do |hands|
  hands.css('strong').zip(hands.css('div.rules-cards')).each do |hand, value|
    hand_hash = {}
    hand_hash[:name] = hand.text
    hand_value = []
    value.css('img').each do |card|
      hand_value << card.attr('src')
      hand_hash[:value] = hand_value
    end
    hands_array << hand_hash #here, now you are saving after each hand
  end
end
hands_array
```

`hands.css('strong').zip(hands.css('div.rules-cards'))` will pair up each *name* and *rule* and then you are just adding that in your `hands_array`.

Result:

> [{:name=>"1. Royal flush",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/A-49a04aae5e96d2f948dc2062c2c4fcd5.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/K-0bfc14d8f58cc13891b108e4178f92f9.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/Q-b981aa1f57642480de1dceaf1c2e810f.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/J-d915fc38dbca1ca74cdd75dd913de1f3.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/T-ef2fe11bbd701e4c5b6681e506271700.png"]},
>   {:name=>"2. Straight flush"},  {:name=>"3. Four of a kind",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Heart/J-2bf19067cda29391286416d0d00646d6.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/J-d915fc38dbca1ca74cdd75dd913de1f3.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/J-fff29c49da8ca1f7a272c5ac83f51d06.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Club/J-58b4c0f26e3e0cf8c0772ab3e9e34784.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/7-7e507c2122efe10ed7abacab95edff97.png"]},
>   {:name=>"4. Full house",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Heart/T-c3f8fd4ffc3e09ec705a817aa212dc86.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/T-ef2fe11bbd701e4c5b6681e506271700.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/T-9a16f63a333b3edeb50c4372f8dd9883.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Club/9-e6f0020a48aef9907b626477c5a60ac2.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/9-3e500833bafc81a708d195f16d005125.png"]},
>   {:name=>"5. Flush",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Spade/4-4200c8b5f3f5ba04d9fd5a69d71dab2f.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/J-fff29c49da8ca1f7a272c5ac83f51d06.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/8-60d335b08119f600c3ca02aa58fa902d.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/2-e2d1cee5fc0db0b70990036153d57906.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/9-b0d71e77734375ceb3954156232f1f2d.png"]},
>   {:name=>"6. Straight",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Club/9-e6f0020a48aef9907b626477c5a60ac2.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/8-6cd5b3025be0dd56cd52dfd2a49d922d.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/7-6c1d119e9c923f8e4773cf00d05e26d6.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/6-a0c0218210a1a6c4ec17e5cec17ee3d8.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Heart/5-f498916a3011c2b7199e1c1008dbe330.png"]},
>   {:name=>"7. Three of a kind",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Club/7-5610625720208cc02c1107c91365eb37.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/7-7e507c2122efe10ed7abacab95edff97.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/7-6c1d119e9c923f8e4773cf00d05e26d6.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Club/K-3e8312c33de4718943cd0276de8a16a1.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/3-909f8b1571f834c774576c93eae26594.png"]},
>   {:name=>"8. Two pair",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Club/4-33a9251d25da1ea2ba49e69e94549aee.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/4-4200c8b5f3f5ba04d9fd5a69d71dab2f.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Club/3-0c3eda54cfb6808b0a94950c045e497a.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/3-909f8b1571f834c774576c93eae26594.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Club/Q-9fcc4fd7692aa96ba9fcb04fa9fd727d.png"]},
>   {:name=>"9. Pair",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Heart/A-748f3f87f79ac475e6a432750725b64c.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/A-49a04aae5e96d2f948dc2062c2c4fcd5.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Club/8-c3708e4821723f1100d514e5280b3f32.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/4-4200c8b5f3f5ba04d9fd5a69d71dab2f.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Heart/7-1610ff3e74c68f6dd8a855bd16887457.png"]},
>   {:name=>"10. High Card",   :value=>
>   ["/packages/cards/Large/Diamond/3-909f8b1571f834c774576c93eae26594.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Club/J-58b4c0f26e3e0cf8c0772ab3e9e34784.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/8-60d335b08119f600c3ca02aa58fa902d.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Heart/4-712ce04b7f2c7e588c48a1e2b46a4244.png",
>       "/packages/cards/Large/Spade/2-e2d1cee5fc0db0b70990036153d57906.png"]}]

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I like the use of `zip` :)

Comment: Good answer. You can replace lines 7 through 11 (and be more idiomatic) by using `map` instead of `each` like so: `hand_hash[:value] = value.css('img').map { |card| card.attr('src') }`. This does result in the second array element having `:value => []`, but I think that is preferable to no `:value` key at all.

Comment: @moveson - yes, I totally get it. The entire thing can actually be rewritten in a more idiomatic way. But my intent is to help OP with his own code for the problem at hand.

Comment: @kiddorails Agreed. But because the code there is somewhat tortured and exhibits the same problem the OP was having to begin with (i.e., line 10 assigns the growing array repeatedly to the same Hash key) I thought it might make sense to help him understand how to properly work with arrays in Ruby.

Comment: @moveson - I agree with you. Would be really glad, if you could add an edit to this answer (or add another) with additional information/code of how OP should have structured his code?

Answer (score 0):

The `doc.css('div#rules-of-poker-accordion')` call is returning a single div, as that is how the page is structured. Because of that, you are only actually entering the `each` loop once.

The layout of that site is a bit funny, so you'll have to get the names and the values separately. Here is a brute force solution...

```
def get_all_hands
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.cardplayer.com/rules-of-poker/hand-rankings'))
  hands_array = []

  doc.css('div#rules-of-poker-accordion').css("strong").each do |name|
    hands_array.push({name: name.text, value: []})
  end

  doc.css('div#rules-of-poker-accordion').css(".rules-cards").each_with_index do |hand, i|
    hand.css('img').each do |card|
      hands_array[i][:value].push card.attr('src')
    end
  end
  hands_array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @kiddorails is correct, but you can be much more concise and Ruby-idiomatic in this problem. Consider the following, which gives the same result:

```
  def get_all_hands
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.cardplayer.com/rules-of-poker/hand-rankings'))
    hands = doc.css('div#rules-of-poker-accordion').first
    hands.css('strong').zip(hands.css('div.rules-cards')).map do |hand, value|
      {name: hand.text, value: value.css('img').map { |card| card.attr('src') }}
    end
  end
```

Ruby has strong methods for handling and transforming Arrays. Once you have an Array, you can transform it using one of Ruby's many expressive [Enumerable methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html). @kiddorails started down this path by using `#zip` to join two arrays together, and the above refactoring finishes the job by taking the resulting array of arrays and transforming it into an array of hashes using `#map`.

In Ruby, anytime you find yourself writing this pattern:

```
result = []
array.each { |element| result << method(element) }
result
```

You can generally replace those three lines with:

```
array.map { |element| method(element) }
```